# Dart Shell.Run issue running the tar command

Tags: shell, dart, tar

I am trying to run a tar command using Dart's Shell.run, but adding './*' at the end of the tar command gives me an error only when running in the Shell.run().  This is not an issue if I run the exact same command on the terminal.  This works fine if ran on the terminal `tar --exclude=example --exclude=test --exclude=package.tar.gz -czvf package.tar.gz ./*`

But calling it from within Dart shell, throws an exception.

```
final tarResult = await shell.clone(verbose: true, commandVerbose: true, commentVerbose: true).run(
      "tar --exclude=example --exclude=test --exclude=$tarName -czvf $tarName ./*",
    );
```

The result is:

```
$ tar --exclude=example --exclude=test --exclude=package.tar.gz -czvf package.tar.gz ./*
/usr/bin/tar: ./*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Unhandled exception:
ShellException(tar --exclude=example --exclude=test --exclude=package.tar.gz -czvf package.tar.gz ./*, exitcode 2, workingDirectory /home/tom/code/plugin_prov/plugin_push_prov
```

At this point it really looks like an issue with Dart Shell and escaping the ./*.  I have tried all possible combination I can think of, but no luck so far.

Suggestions?

Comment: `./*` is replaced with an actual list _by a shell_; the tar command you give expects this to already be done before it starts. If Dart's "shell" library doesn't run a POSIX shell, that implies it's _your_ work to do glob expansion.

Comment: I don't know Dart, but to give you an example -- in Python there's a `glob` library, so one can run `glob.glob('./*')` to return a list of matching filenames ready to append to an argv array (and note "array", not string -- if you're not using a shell, better to just build an argument vector yourself so you have full control)